# PDO Execute Issue with $_POST Variables

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I'm running into trouble when I'm trying to insert something into my database using `$_POST` variables.

Currently this is how I have it setup. When I pass these variables to it, it works. Notice I set everything to 1 in the working example.

```
$video_id = 1;
$user_id = 1;
$session_id = 1;
$user_rating = 1;

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=db_name", $username, $password);
    $q = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO video_rating (rating, video_id, user_id, sessionid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

$q->execute(array($user_rating, $video_id, $user_id, $user_rating));
```

However, when I use my POST variables

```
$video_id = $_POST['video_id'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$session_id = $_POST['session_id'];
$user_rating = $_POST['user_rating'];
```

and run the same PDO execute, it doesn't work.

My form looks like this.

```
<form id="rate-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="auto-submit-star" type="radio" name="user-rating" value="1" title="Very poor"/>
<input class="auto-submit-star" type="radio" name="user-rating" value="2" title="Poor"/>
<input class="auto-submit-star" type="radio" name="user-rating" value="3" title="OK"/>
<input class="auto-submit-star" type="radio" name="user-rating" value="4" title="Good"/>
<input class="auto-submit-star" type="radio" name="user-rating" value="5" title="Very Good"/>
<span id="hover-test" style="margin:0 0 0 15px;" class="rate-text"></span>
<input type="hidden" name="video_id" value="251"/>
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="rate_form" />  
</form>
```

Can you see something I might be overlooking as to why it's not working.

Comment: What does a `var_dump()` of `$_POST` produce?

Comment: Please , stop using emulated prepares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is looking for:

```
 $user_rating = $_POST['user_rating'];
```

Your HTML includes:

```
 <input class="auto-submit-star" type="radio" name="user-rating" ...
```

I assume one or the other is a typo - when your SQL is being generated, `$user_rating` is coming through as NULL, and your table doesn't allow null entries in that field.

Comment: That was a typo, thanks for catching that. But that still didn't fix the problem of nothing is showing up in the db.

Comment: In that case, have you tried checking to see if the database is returning an error when you make the insert?

Comment: I'd probably also lose the ` enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the form, too.

Comment: I didn't have that initially, only added it when trying to figure out this issue.

Comment: I also have, `catch(PDOException $e)
 {
 echo $e->getMessage();
 }` and nothing is showing up there

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($q->errorInfo())` after execute. I don't think that a failed query actually generates an exception.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the suggestion, it's outputting `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails `

Comment: Can you check and make sure that all the variables are being populated with data?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. The foreign key constraint issue is because I was trying to add a an id for a video that didn't exist in the video table. And that was causing all those issues. Thanks for the help!